In a new VSCode SCM extension, how do you remove SourceControlResourceGroups from the SourceControl object so they are not visible in the SCM view?
I'm writing my own SCM extension for use at work.  It was developed a long time ago and is somewhat unique, but it isn't going away any time soon, so I thought I'd try to build an extension to make it a little more accessible for our users.
We have one central repository that contains common code as well as project-specific stuff.  As such the repository has many folders and often >1000 files associated with a given project.  It becomes useful to organize the SCM view by the folder structure, or by tags.  I can read in all the information for a given project, but I am struggling with how to present the information in the SCM view.
I want to allow the user to pick how things are organized, by folder path or by tag.  I know how to generate the model for the SCM view.  The problem is switching from one format to the other.  I can't get the view to update when the user toggles the given setting.  It just adds the new structure to the bottom of the existing list.  And it keeps adding each time the setting is toggled.  Only when I exit and re-launch the extension host (exit and hit F5 again from my extension dev) then the view clears out and only shows the information based on the last option that was selected.
I built up my resourceGroups using the [] syntax so I can define them by name instead of by index.  This all works fine.  But when I try to empty the array, or dispose of the resource groups, it doesn't have any impact on the SCM view itself.  I was expecting that any of these actions would trigger the SCM view to refresh.
I've even tried looping through each of the resourceStates arrays and disposing of them individually.  I've also tried disposing of the SourceControl object and building a new one, but it just adds a new repository to the view without removing the disposed one.  Although at least in that case it doesn't append to the existing view, I just have 2 views of the same repository organized differently.
I also tried setting the hiddenWhenEmpty flag but that doesn't seem to do anything either.
Here's my current code (at least the pertinent pieces of it):
const vscode  = require('vscode');
const globals = require('./globals');

let tagResourceGroups = [];
let pathResourceGroups = [];

function addResourceStateToGroup(resourceGroup, uri, status) {
  // const resourceState = {
  const resourceState = vscode.SourceControlResourceState = {
      resourceUri: uri,
      command: {
          command: 'vscode.open',
          title: 'Open File',
          arguments: [uri]
      },
      decorations: {
          tooltip: status,
          strikeThrough: false,
          faded: false
      }
  };
  resourceGroup.resourceStates = [...resourceGroup.resourceStates, resourceState];
}


function buildResourceGroups() {
  // this didn't work
  // tagResourceGroups   = [];
  // pathResourceGroups  = [];

  console.log( 'reinitializing resource group lists...');
  // this doesn't work either.
  tagResourceGroups.forEach( rgLoc => { 
    forEach( resStat => { resStat.dispose(); } ); 
    rgLoc.dispose(); 
  });
  pathResourceGroups.forEach( rgLoc => { 
    forEach( resStat => { resStat.dispose(); } ); 
    rgLoc.dispose(); 
  });

  sortTreeMode = globals.config.sortTreeMode;
  console.log( `sortTreeMode = ${sortTreeMode}`);

  console.log('building resource groups...');
  if( sortTreeMode === 'path' ) {
    pathList.forEach( path => {
      if( path !== undefined && path !== '' ) {
        pathResourceGroups[path] = sourceControl.createResourceGroup(path, path);
        pathResourceGroups[path].hideWhenEmpty = true;
      }
    });
  }
  else if( sortTreeMode === 'tag' ) {
    tagList.forEach( tag => {
      if( tag !== undefined && tag !== '' ) {
        tagResourceGroups[tag] = sourceControl.createResourceGroup( tag, tag);
        tagResourceGroups[tag].hideWhenEmpty = true;
      }
    });
  }

  let resourceStatus='';
  let filePath='';

  console.log( 'buidling resource states and assigning...');
  resourceSum.forEach( resource => {
    if( resource !== undefined && resource.fullPath !== undefined ) {
      if( resource.managed === '1') { resourceStatus = 'Unchanged'; }
      else                          { resourceStatus = 'Modified'};

      filePath = resource.fullPath;
      
      if( sortTreeMode === 'path' && resource.scope !== undefined && resource.scope !== '' ) {
        addResourceStateToGroup(pathResourceGroups[resource.path], vscode.Uri.file( filePath ), resourceStatus);
      }
      else if( sortTreeMode === 'tag' && resource.parTagName !== undefined && resource.parTagName !== '') {
        addResourceStateToGroup(tagResourceGroups[resource.parTagName], vscode.Uri.file( filePath ), resourceStatus);
      }
    }
  });
}


